# How to remove the backlash from the end if the URL in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I am having a issue where I have to remove the backlash(/) from the end of the url. actually I had removed last path component by using deleting url.deletingLastPathComponent() and now generated url contains / at the end. So how can I remove it to make the url workable.

[image]

Comment: The url is workable even with a **slash** at the end (by the way back**s**lash is `<\>` and backlash  means *striking back* or *retroaction*)

Comment: You can covert your URL back to string using url.absoluteString and then make change in string you get and then convert that string in URL.

Comment: Thank you @vadian for pointing out my mistake I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @NamraParmar Thanks this is working fine. But there is an other issue, the issue is that the spaces in the name of the url is been replaced by %2520, how can I save my self from that as the name than can not be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should work fine**. Coming to required answer, we can't do string manipulation for URLs. Solution would be

1. Remove last path component
2. Remove /
3. Create url again

```
    url.deleteLastPathComponent()
    var address = url.absoluteString

    address.removeLast()

    url = URL(string: address)
```

Spaces are being replaced by %20 because of URL encoding. e.g.

```
var name = "Rajesh Budhiraja"
name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

now name will be 'Rajesh%20Budhiraja'

you can undo this via

```
name.removingPercentEncoding
```

Comment: Thanks this is working fine. But there is an other issue, the issue is that the spaces in the name of the url is been replaced by %20 (or any other number) how can I save my self from that as the name than can not be matched.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, name.removingPercentEncoding worked out to be fine one